# How to compile/install node.js(could not configure a cxx compiler!) (Ubuntu). 

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, installation, node.js

How can I compile/install node.js on Ubuntu? It failed with an error about `cxx compiler`.

Comment: Because you didn't actually ask a question, it seems.

Comment: Okay I updated post to be more like a question I guess

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**One-liner** to install all needed dependencies(curl and git are not really needed, but are very useful and also needed if you install via nvm).

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git-core
```

Last two dependencies are not always needed, but installing them is really usefull anyway and you probably need it later anyway.

To only install **cxx compiler**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

If **openssl** is missing

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: I also found this very good tutorial explaining how to install node.js on ubuntu => http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 45):

If like me, you are attempting to install this on an AWS instance running Amazon Linux AMI (which looks to be a cut down version CentOS):

Install base tools:

`yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

Now install openssl-devel:

`yum install openssl-devel`

Node should compile fine now.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Saved me tons of time.

Answer (score 8):

If you're attempting this on Win7 like me, running:

```
ash.exe
$ /bin/rebaseall
```

...did the trick.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you should make this a separate topic if it does not exist. Then when users google for compiling node.js for windows they will find your topic.

Comment: Should be worth noting that Nicholas is compiling node in Windows using cygwin. `ash.exe` and `rebaseall.exe` are utilities that ship with cygwin.

Comment: Running `ash.exe` in bash gave me weird output. I opened a normal `cmd` instead, and ran `cd C:/cygwin/bin,`, then `dash.exe` (A better `ash.exe` supposedly, but either works). Then used `./rebaseall`

Answer (score 6):

If you find yourself getting this error on Mac OSX, you need to install XCode.

https://developer.apple.com/

Comment: I also heard this of a friend of mine using macosx

Comment: this should be on your installation DVD. at least it was on my copy of snow leopard.

Comment: I have Xcode installed from the app store and still get this error.

Comment: @quantumpotato same here with mountain lion :(

Comment: Try sudo. Had same issue but managed to get it to build with `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` then using sudo to configure/install.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to run `yum install gcc-c++` on Cent OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package for it on launchpad.
https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

Answer (score 2):

**For Node.js v6:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**For Node.js v7:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

**Optional: install build tools**
To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

After to get latest NPM packages, if you need:

```
npn update -g
```

[Partial source here.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)