# Are there any precompiled binaries for V8?

Tags: node.js, v8

V8 is an important part of node.js, which uses the Google V8 Javascript engine. Building V8 on my windows box [Windows 7/64-bit] is going to take me hours of grabbing and installing tools I'm not familiar with (though I do use Cygwin). It'd save me a lot of headaches if there were some binary installers out there. Google search didn't return any obvious locations - do the guru's here know of any?

Even if you don't know of any for my exact environment, sharing others here would help folks in the same boat...

Comment: Doesn't node.js include a copy of v8 with its source and automatically builds it?

Comment: By inspection, that's true. Perhaps I'm trapped into building it, but it'd still be useful to have a source for v8 binaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no V8 binary in node.js. Instead, V8 is bound into the node.js binary.

Just build it on Cygwin like everyone else. If, like me you have to use an XP SP3 Atom powered netbook, then type make, and go to bed. In the morning it is done.

0.5.0pre build fine on Cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen Node 0.5.2 ?

http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/07/22/node-v0-5-2/

There's a new windows exe : http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.5.2/node.exe

Also perf is getting there...

Linux 6878 req/sec - Windows 4582 req/sec

Answer (score 3):

As of Node.js v0.6.5 or so, binary installers are now provided:

http://nodejs.org/#download

The Windows MSI Installer (direct download link):
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.msi

MacOS DMG Image (direct download link):
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/node-v0.6.6.pkg

For Linux, I still prefer my own RPM builder:
https://github.com/ddopson/nodejs-rpm-builder

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't help you with your windows(cygwin) problem. I completely switched over to Ubuntu(linux).

I think you should not be running(production) node.js from windows(performance issues). Node.js is highly optimized for *nix like distros(they only support [/dev/poll, kqueue(2), event ports, select(2), poll(2) and epoll(4)](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)). On Ubuntu it is really easy to [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329355/node-js-could-not-configure-a-cxx-compiler) node.js.

Comment: Installing linux(ubuntu) is a sinse. You can have them both run next to each other. My advice is to do that. You can be up in running in an hour!

Comment: Installing ubuntu in a virtual box is another easy option.  Personally I have node running in cygwin, in a virtual box and on a linode.

Comment: yeah that is also an option(especially if you want to only use if for simple development :)), but natively it will run smoother.

Comment: Got it running under cygwin just fine.

Comment: very good :). But when you are going to benchmark it, I bet you the performance is going to suck!

Answer (score 1):

*In case anyone else come across this older question, updating with latest situation...*

As of version 0.8.6, node.js distributes binaries (not just installers) for all supported platforms:

http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/07/node-v0-8-6-stable/

You can find the latest stable version at this location:

http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/

And the download page gives you a different matrix linking to these same files:

http://nodejs.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

I found prebuild packages for many v8 versions binaries at https://www.nuget.org/
i.e.:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/v8-v140-x64/

Its not very obvious but on the right side there is a download button.
Redistributables and symbol files also available

Answer (score 0):

The following link downloads a .zip archive containing:

- d8.exe: V8’s own developer shell https://v8.dev/docs/d8
- icudtl.dat
- snapshot_blob.bin
- v8_build_config.json

https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-v8/official/canary/v8-win64-rel-11.4.28.zip

Replace 11.4.28 with the desired version.
https://v8.dev/docs/version-numbers