# NPM Install error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to get my app to run locally. In an attempt to install NPM in the folder I am receiving an error when it hits to:

```
npm ERR! error installing contextify@0.0.7
```

I have searched the web but all of the results turned up people getting errors get in Windows7. Im using OSX. I have XCode installed.

Below you will find the whole print out:

```
gorteks$ npm install
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser
npm WARN htmlparser@1.7.3 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify

> contextify@0.0.7 preinstall /Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-app/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build

Nothing to clean (project not configured)
Setting srcdir to                        : /Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-   app/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify 
Setting blddir to                        : /Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-app/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build 
Checking for program g++ or c++          : not found 
/Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-  app/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/wscript:11: error: could   not configure a cxx compiler!
npm ERR! error installing contextify@0.0.7
npm ERR! error installing jsdom@0.2.10
npm ERR! error installing jquery@1.6.3
npm ERR! contextify@0.0.7 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.0.7 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 10.8.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-app
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-beta-10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message contextify@0.0.7 preinstall: `node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf       configure build`
npm ERR! message `sh "-c" "node-waf clean || (exit 0); node-waf configure build"` failed   with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gorteks/Sites/digidj-app/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: update `node`, update `npm`, try again.  If it still fails, complain to the author of `contextify`

Answer (score 4):

I used Xcode 4.3 from the Apple App Store and I had to install the Unix Command line tools. This can be done via Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Command Line Tools

Answer (score 2):

**"error: could   not configure a cxx compiler!"**

You need a C++ compiler. Your using OSX, so you need to install XCode.

Here is a SO answer on the issue that include various ways to solve this error for different OSs/Distros:

[How to compile/install node.js(could not configure a cxx compiler!) (Ubuntu).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329355/node-js-could-not-configure-a-cxx-compiler-ubuntu)

Comment: I have XCode. Forgot to mention I checked that too. My version:    Version 4.0.2

Comment: Did you have the "Unix Tools" option checked when you installed it?

Comment: May also look at this: http://www.techskater.com/web-stuff/problems-installing-node-js-on-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of Xcode, upgrade from 4.0 to 4.1

Comment: It's so retarded that you have to download XCode through the App Store now. When I try, it says I need Lion. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! Heres what worked for me.
I installed Lion and updated XCode.
Simple but time consuming.