# Dockerfile build error on RUN npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, docker

I run a Docker build, using a Dockerfile to build an image. But I get an error on npm install:

Dockerfile :

```
# Download Runnable-web Repo
RUN eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null && ssh-add /.ssh/id_rsa && git clone git@github.com:CodeNow/runnable-web.git 

WORKDIR runnable-web 
RUN npm install 
RUN bower install  --allow-root
```

Error:

```
Step 5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 3fefdf5af71d
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/runnable-web/package.json'
 If you need help, you may report this log at:
     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
 or email it to:
     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

 Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
 "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926425/docker-having-trouble-running-npm-install-after-creating-a-new-user

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844708/npm-install-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dockerfile/npm: create a sudo user to run npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906419/dockerfile-npm-create-a-sudo-user-to-run-npm-install)

Comment: Are you sure the git command is cloning the repo into the /runnable-web/ directory? That error looks to me like the file isn't found (but it is present in the git repo, in the root), so maybe  you're not cloning into the correct directory. Try moving your WORKDIR command above your RUN?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in Directory `C:\` which is a shared driver.It throws the same error with yours.

[image]

Then I move `Dockerfile` to a sub directory like `C:\Intel` and cd it to run `docker build .`, it works

[image]

So I guess `Dockerfile` should not be placed in shared dirver root directory.